# Find repeated strings in csv file

Tags: awk

I have one file called `api.csv` who sends some information in the following format:

```
vm-foo-bar;2021-04-26T08:16:01Z
vm-foo-bar2;2020-03-31T18:16:01Z
vm-foo-bar;2021-04-27T08:16:01Z
3482764892;2021-04-21T10:12:01Z
423174923;2021-04-26T08:16:01Z
423174923;2021-05-26T08:16:01Z
```

in the first **columns** we have a some random hostname, in second **columns** we have the last seen status of this hosts, I want to filter all repeated hostnames and save to a `$var`, this file have more than 1000 hosts and last seen statuses.

I tried something like this:

```
'{ a[$0]++ } END{ for(x in a) if(a[x]>1) print a[x], x }'
```

But the real problem of this, is the command doesn't show which are the repeated strings, I expected something like this:

```
vm-foo-bar;2021-04-26T08:16:01Z
vm-foo-bar;2021-04-27T08:16:01Z
423174923;2021-04-26T08:16:01Z
423174923;2021-05-26T08:16:01Z
```

I don't have anymore ideas to solve this question, I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: You're talking about columns, not rows.

Comment: That's Awk code, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sort api.csv | sed 's/\([^;]*\).*/&\t\1/' | uniq -f1 -D | cut -f1
423174923;2021-04-26T08:16:01Z
423174923;2021-05-26T08:16:01Z
vm-foo-bar;2021-04-26T08:16:01Z
vm-foo-bar;2021-04-27T08:16:01Z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var=$(awk -F\; 'NR == FNR { ++a[$1]; next } a[$1] > 1' api.csv api.csv)
```